# I am getting a MessageHandlingException (NullPointerException) for second implementation

Tags: spring-integration

I have made a Local transaction configuration wherein the listener reads a message from the Queue , populate the DB and post it to topic. This is working for me . In the same application I will recieve a second type of feed and I need to implement in the same manner i.e. a second listener will read the message from the queue ,populate the other table in Db and post it to a second topic as part of a single transaction (a second JmsTransactionManager). However for the second implementation I am getting a MessageHandlingException (NullPointerException). Please advise.

Implementation detail :- I am using Hibernate layer for persistance . I am populating the entities and then persisting to DB using Hibernate and sending the message to the Topic from Java in a single method annotated with @Transactional.

Comment: please share relevant code snippet, your description alone is not going to help much here

Comment: +stacktrace and config